# Consuming ASP.Net web service with ColdFusion

Tags: asp.net, web-services, coldfusion

I am creating an ASP.Net web site to log errors for our ColdFusion sites. The ASP site is exposing a couple of web service methods that I would like to pass in information about the error. To test the whole process I am doing the following:

```
[WebMethod]
public string InsertEvent(string iAppID) {
    return "Hello, " + iAppID;
}

<cffunction name="TestWebService2" access="remote" returntype="Any" >
    <cfinvoke method="InsertEvent" webservice="http://somewebsite.org/LogEvent.asmx?WSDL" >
        <cfinvokeargument name="iAppID" value="andy" >
    </cfinvoke>
</cffunction>
```

I can call the web service with the ColdFusion cfinvoke tag as long as there are no parmeters that need to be passed in. If I add the parameters to the web service, and try passing them to the service I get the following error:

Web service operation InsertEvent with parameters {iAppID={1}} cannot be found.

Does the ColdFusion server cache the web service call? Or am I missing something else?

Thanks

Comment: CF does cache web service definitions/artifacts. So be sure to add [`refreshWSDL="true"`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e0a.html) after making changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try invoking the webservice like this:

```
<cfset ws = createObject("webservice","http://somewebsite.org/LogEvent.asmx?WSDL") />
<cfset result = ws.InsertEvent("Test Striong") />
<cfdump var="#result#" />
```